# python extracting second number in a line if meets a criteria

Tags: python, text, numbers, extract

I want to extract the second number in each line from a text doc if that line has 'command' in it. I want command and the rest of the line printed next to the number on those that do. there are hundreds of lines.

The lines look like :

```
1376328501.285|1166703600|0|SimControl|4|Command 72FB0007: AC28200 - "Thrst History Reset" to DCDR 0 time=62
```

this line if programmed how I need should come out

```
1166703600 Command 72FB0007: AC28200 - "Thrst History Reset" to DCDR 0 time=62
```

how do I do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Comment: i am new. i tried a bunch of things for a couple days and was so lost i didnt know what to do. thanks for your help anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Treat the data like CSV data (albeit separated by a pipe), with the [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html):

```
import csv

with open('inputfile', 'rb') as inputfile:
    reader = csv.reader(inputfile, delimiter='|')
    for row in reader:
        if len(row) > 5 and row[5].lower().startswith('command'):
            print row[1], row[5]
```

The `csv.reader()` gives you an iterator yielding a list for each row; your sample line would result in:

```
['1376328501.285', '1166703600', '0', 'SimControl', '4', 'Command 72FB0007: AC28200 - "Thrst History Reset" to DCDR 0 time=62']
```

Indices start at 0, so the column with the `Command` text is `row[5]`; the second column number is in `row[1]`. The above code tests if there are enough columns in the current row and if `row[5]`, when lowercased, starts with the word `command`.

The above assumes Python 2; for Python 3 it looks subtly different:

```
import csv

with open('inputfile', newline='') as inputfile:
    reader = csv.reader(inputfile, delimiter='|')
    for row in reader:
        if len(row) > 5 and row[5].lower().startswith('command'):
            print(row[1], row[5])
```

Comment: for some reason I am getting a syntax error on the 'print row[1], row[5]' line pointing at the 'w' in 'row[1]'. any ideas?

Comment: @user2938428: Are you using Python 3 perhaps? This answer uses Python 2 syntax.

Comment: @user2938428: Are you sure? The syntax error you see is *exactly* what you'd see when using Python 3. There is no syntax error in the code I posted otherwise.

Comment: yeah i put it "print (row[1], row[5])" and it is working now. for some reason it says "IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: "

Comment: i even used "import sys
sys.path.append("U:\dulcanm\Thor7DSS\Filter LOG commands")"

Comment: @user2938428: Then you are definitely using Python 3. The `IOError` is thrown because Python cannot find the file you specified. Make sure you use an absolute path (and beware of `\` backslashes in Windows paths).

Comment: it cant find the input file

Comment: `'inputfile'` is just an *example* filename. Do make sure you replace that with a real filename.

Comment: i did and it is in the folder i appended

Comment: `sys.path` has *nothing* to do with opening files with `open()`. That's only for Python import files. Use `r"U:\dulcanm\Thor7DSS\Filter LOG commands\<filename>"` as a *full* path to the filename. Note the `r` at the start to prevent `\` from being interpreted as an escape code.

Comment: it still cant find the file. i made sure the characters are exact.

Comment: i place it on the line like so?:
r"U:\dulcanm\Thor7DSS\Filter LOG commands\filename.log"

Comment: Yes, that looks like a valid, full path. Are you 100% certain that that filename exists?

Comment: yeah i am. I was running thru a map drive so i tried moving it local. then i tried with another file i need to run the script on and again not found.

Comment: @user2938428: what does `import os; print os.listdir(r'U:\dulcanm\Thor7DSS\Filter LOG commands')` tell you is there?

Comment: no such file or directory. is there a chance it is a permissions issue? i have looked but cannot find a reason so far

Comment: @user2938428: Trace this back; is `r'U:\dulcanm\Thor7DSS'` listable? Etc.

Comment: turned out since i was running through an external server i had to save all the files in the home directory of my sandbox. thanks again for all your help

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> l = """1376328501.285|1166703600|0|SimControl|4|Command 72FB0007: AC28200 - "Thrst History Reset" to DCDR 0 time=62"""
>>> l = [l,l,l]

>>> [ele.split("|")[1] for ele in l if "command" in ele.lower()]
['1166703600', '1166703600', '1166703600']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lines = '1376328501.285|1166703600|0|SimControl|4|Command 72FB0007: AC28200 - "Thrst History Reset" to DCDR 0 time=62'

if 'Command' in lines:
    lines_lst = lines.split('|')
    what_you_want = lines_lst[1] + ' '+ lines_lst[-1]

print what_you_want
>>> 1166703600 Command 72FB0007: AC28200 - "Thrst History Reset" to DCDR 0 time=62
```

So, if you have a file containing thousands of lines like this:

```
f = open(YOUR_FILE, 'r')
data = f.readlines()
f.close()

foo = []
for lines in data:
    if 'Command' in lines:
        lines_lst = lines.split('|')
        what_you_want = lines_lst[1] + ' '+ lines_lst[-1]
        foo.append(what_you_want)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

s = '''
1376328501.285|1166703600|0|SimControl|4|Command aaaaa
12347801.2|11660|0|Sim|5|Command bbb
13587918501.1|13|0|XCF|6|cccccc
101.285|285|0|pof|7|ddddd
137501|-2.87|457|run|8|Command eeee
'''
print s

regx = re.compile('^[^|]+\|([^|]+).+?(Command.+\n?)',
                  re.MULTILINE)

print ''.join('%s %s' % m.groups() for m in regx.finditer(s))
```

result

```
1376328501.285|1166703600|0|SimControl|4|Command aaaaa
12347801.2|11660|0|Sim|5|Command bbb
13587918501.1|13|0|XCF|6|cccccc
101.285|285|0|pof|7|ddddd
137501|-2.87|457|run|8|Command eeee

1166703600 Command aaaaa
11660 Command bbb
-2.87 Command eeee
```